# How to allow packets for WS-Discovery (onvif)?

Tags: networking, firewall, ufw

I have a Linux machine with ufw firewall, a program runs WS-Discovery that works as intended when ufw is disabled but fails to return anything when it is enabled, what I tried without success:

- Enabling outgoing traffic `sudo ufw default allow outgoing`
- Allowing both 3702/udp and 1900/udp

What am I missing here?

Comment: what does your `ufw status verbose` report?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found couple of solutions:

- The first one using `ipset` as detailed in [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/250797/stateful-matching-of-multicast-responses-in-iptables/911286#911286) to [Stateful matching of multicast responses in iptables](https://serverfault.com/q/250797); replace 1900 with 3702 as that's the port used for WS-discovery.
- The second one which I used, is to allow incoming packets whose source port is 3702; with ufw you do it like this:

  ```
  ufw allow proto udp from 172.16.0.0/16 port 3702 to any
  ```

Comment: Please use `-` for list items, not `_`.